# How to run the triggers in Google app script without reauth each time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, blogger

Hello I have a script which is not a web app but it is an API based one  it fetch data from json and sent them to blogger as post , and I am running this function with time based trigger , but after some run I need to open the auth url and get verification .. How can I avoid that and run the triggers continues 
This is the auth code

```
var service = getBloggerService_();

if (service.hasAccess()) {
var api ='https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/' + blogId + '/posts/';

var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getBloggerService_().getAccessToken()
};

var options = {
  'headers': headers,
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload': body,
  'muteHttpExceptions': false
};

try {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api, options);

  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  Logger.log(responseCode);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(json);
}
catch(err) {
  Logger.log(err); // error with url fetch call
}
  }
else {
 var  authorizationUrll=service.getAuthorizationUrl();
 Logger.log('Open the following URL and 
re-run the script: %s',
    authorizationUrl);
```

}
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Add the Blogger scope in appsscript.json manually.

  ```
  {
    ...
    "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
    ],
    ...
  }
  ```
- You can then use:

  ```
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); //contains Blogger scope always
  };
  ```
- You don't need to use `service` or any other library.

#### References:

- [Setting Explicit scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)
- [ScriptApp#getOAuthToken](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken())

Comment: Well I am getting more errors : look like scriptApp is not defined if i define i need to change the whole coding ,If have some time help with this code;[Link] (https://github.com/BitzTrail/NewsAPI-to-Blogspot.com/blob/master/newsapi.gs)

Comment: @arvs Uppercase `S` in `ScriptApp`. Most of your code is unnecessary. You don't need `OAuth2` library.

Comment: Not working still getting some error as no authorization , I have posted the entire script above , may be you can correct and contribute something into that , as i am newbie in coding i dont  know much about the java script ..that is a newsapi to blogger script <